# Chrome extension content script: click() and async results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

On certain pages, my chrome extension injects code that scrapes a few DOM nodes' text & sends it to the background script.

One such node is only visible after clicking a button that fires an async call--it's a small popup `div` that appears a few milliseconds after clicking.

I thought about just replicating the button's `onClick` code in my content script, but the js is pretty complicated & uglified so I'm not yet able to figure out what the call is doing. I'm also not sure if it's possible to access the namespace of a site's js from a content script.

My plan now is to just call the button's `.click()` method & scrape the resultant `div`, but the scraper can't find the `div`.

I figured it might be an async delay problem, so to test this I set a lengthy timeout:

```
document.querySelector('#buttonId').click();
setTimeout(console.log(document.querySelector('#popupDiv').innerText), 4500);
```

Unfortunately, the delayed function still returns `null`.

Is there a better means of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using querySelector with ids, you need to prepend them with "#".

You also need to wrap your timeout in an anonymous function.

```
document.querySelector("#buttonId").click()
setTimeout(function() {
 console.log(document.querySelector("#popupDiv").textContent)
}, 4500)
```

Comment: ah! thank you.  for posterity: the '#' was a transcription error on my part when simplifying selector strings (which I've edited in the OP).  Once I corrected the console.log() function, it worked like a charm, even on a tiny delay of 500 ms.